# Is it a Transitive Set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is $\{\{0\},\{\{0\}\}\}$ a transitive set? Or only $\{0,\{0\},\{\{0\}\}\}$ is transitive?

if the first isnt a transitive set, can someone give me an example of a transitive set which does not contain urelements?

Thanks!

Comment: @vadim123: That would be a set that DOES contain urelements. (Whether such a set can be transitive depends on the exact definition of "transitive" you're working with).

Comment: $\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\},\{\{\varnothing\}\}\}$ is a transitive set that does NOT contain urelements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $0\in\{0\}$ and $\{0\}\in\{\{0\},\{\{0\}\}\}$, but $0\notin\{\{0\},\{\{0\}\}\}$, so no, it is not transitive.

$\{\}$ is transitive and has no urelements.

Comment: okay, I got it... thanks!